# Restart only single application Apache Server

Tags: java, linux, server, putty, database-administration

**I have 3 application running on Apache server.
When restart server all application get restarted.
Anyone can explain how to restart single application without affecting other applications in linux.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can't restart Apache for a single website.

Runnin `/sbin/service httpd restart` for example will restart Apache as whole, there's no way to restart a single application.

Comment: Is their a way so we can create service of our application or something like that so we can start and stop that particular service?

Answer (score 0):

When you say Apache Server, you mean Apache Tomcat? In Tomcat, you can go to the manager page. It's usually in `localhost:8080/manager/html`. On this page you can start, stop, deploy, undeploy, etc. a single web application. See the Tomcat Manager App How To documentation for more details. Then do a `tail -f catalina.out`, it should say what app has been started/stopped/deployed/etc.

Answer (score -1):

Simple workaround  is to touch specific web.xml file using command `touch web.xml`.

Tomcat reloads application every time when it notices change in web.xml file, here we are not modifying web.xml file but just touching it.